# Password sync with Chrome

Tags: sync, password

I know about Xmarks and LastPass, but is there a free solution for password syncing between Android and Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Keepass](http://keepass.info/download.html) is an option. You can set up the [KeePassDroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.android.keepass&hl=en) app to use a password database that you keep synced with [Dropbox](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dropbox.android&hl=en) (a good tutorial is available at [AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/03/30/tutorial-sync-passwords-across-computers-and-android-with-keepass/)). Not very elegant, but it might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to try http://phonemarks.blogspot.com/

Comment: Thanks, but that is just for bookmarks. I was asking for a tool for password sync.